# Jaimini vs Parashara in astrology

Tags: astrology, parashara, jaimini

While one can easily read up on the differences between these two schools of astrology on the web, I am more interested in understanding their popularity through the ages.

Which of the two is older? 
Around which time period in history did Parashara school get more more popular ? Any evidences on the schools of astrology followed by Hindu kings in medieval era ?